# How can i use AdSense with my Firefox/Chrome extension? (is there anyway?)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, adsense

I have a website and I display my AdSense ads there.

I also develop a Firefox/Chrome extension for a browser game.
In order not to put a price to my extension I want to display some adds.
This means that my ads will be on a domain I don't own and I don't know how Google can verify them.

Can I put my ad on my web page and let my addon users see them from an iframe? I am worried that doing this will lead to getting my account banned.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easy enough to research in the [AdSense Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms). Section 5 (prohibited uses) says in particular:

> (vi) directly or indirectly access, launch, and/or activate Ads, Links, Search Results, or Referral Buttons through or from, or **otherwise incorporate the Ads**, Links, Search Results, or Referral Buttons in, any software application, Web site, or other means **other than Your Property(ies)**, and then only to the extent expressly permitted by this Agreement;

Which pretty certainly means that displaying ads in websites your don't own will lead to suspension as soon as this behavior is noticed. In other words: no, you cannot do this, at least not for long.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
In our company we do it and not getting banned, we use div injection, not an iFrame.

Comment: `not getting banned` ... _yet_.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `iFrame`, as [Adsense doesn't allow that](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-ads-in-iframe/19457/).

Another interesting thing is that you can display ads of other networks. `Google Chrome` team allows such [extensions](http://browserfame.com/751/chrome-extension-advertisement) in `WebStore`.